# Why they use backface-visibility:hidden, though a flippable card work fine without it?

Tags: html, css

In many tutorial, they use backface-visibility:hidden to make a flippable card. But it(card) works fine without backface-visibility:hidden. So why they use it? Any solution.
Css:

```
.scene {         
        width: 200px;         
        height: 260px;         
        perspective: 600px;     
        }          
 .card {         
        width: 100%;         
        height: 100%;         
        position: relative;         
        transition: transform 1s;                  
        transform-style: preserve-3d;     
        } 
.card:hover{
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
 .card__face {         
             position: absolute;         
             height: 100%;         
             width: 100%;         
             backface-visibility: ; 
             /*works fine without backface-visibility:hidden */   
             }          
 .card__face--front {         
                     background: red; 
                    }     
 .card__face--back {         
                     background: blue;         
                     transform: rotateY( 180deg );     
                     }
```

Link: https://codepen.io/nur49/pen/QWKaQRv

Comment: `backface-visibility: ; ` <-- This is not valid CSS.

Comment: The reason why the back card doesn't showed up because the `position: absolute;` in the example. It merge 2 card in one place so you can't see the back card. Try removing the `position: absolute;` from `.card__face`

Answer (score 0):

What it does is determine whether the image will show when flipped. A use case would be if you only have content on one side and not the other as in [this](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_backface-visibility) example. If you don't add the css rule, you will still see it through the other side, but obviously backwards. Typically you do see flipcards with info on both sides, so most cases it might not be entirely necessary. Below is the code example from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_backface-visibility).

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#div1 {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#div2 {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h1>The backface-visibility Property</h1>

<p>This example shows the back face of two div elements.</p>

<p>This div element has "backface-visibility: hidden", and the back face of the div element is invisible:</p>
<div id="div1">DIV 1</div>

<p>This div element has "backface-visibility: visible", and the back face of the div element shows a mirror image of the front face:</p>
<div id="div2">DIV 2</div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The backface-visibility property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions. Safari supports it with a webkit prefix.</p>
```

Comment: The reason why the back card doesn't showed up because the `position: absolute;` in the example. It merge 2 card in one place so you can't see the back card. Try removing the `position: absolute;`